# should I use state in addling a new component on click React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am new to react and trying to refactor some es6 js code in to react I have a component that I need to create once I click on an icon similar to insert adjacent html is vanilla js any idea how can I achieve this.

```js
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Item from './Item';

import { icon, library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faPlusCircle} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faPlusCircle)

function row(props) {

const [item] = useState(<Item />)

    return (
        <ul className="global">
        item
        <FontAwesomeIcon onClick={()=>{return <ChangeableItem/>}}   con={["fas", "plus-circle"]}/>
        <ul/>
        )
     }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This doesn't do anything:

```
onClick={()=>{return <ChangeableItem/>}}
```

The click handler isn't expecting a returned React node and won't do anything with it.

> should I use state

Yes.  Track in state whether or not this component is displayed.  For example:

```
const [showChangeableItem, setShowChangeableItem] = useState(false);
```

The state now says not to show the "changeable item".  Within the rendering, conditionally render that element based on state.  For example:

```
{ showChangeableItem ? <ChangeableItem/> : null }
```

Then in your click handler you'd just update the state:

```
<FontAwesomeIcon onClick={() => setShowChangeableItem(true)} con={["fas", "plus-circle"]}/>
```

Basically, don't think of it as trying to add elements.  All of the elements you need should already be specified in the render, some can just be wrapped in conditional logic.  State drives the rendering.  Events update state.

Comment: working but how can I add more like I want start from none to like 5-6

Comment: @Jackhammer: You'd track that information in state.  For example, if you want to track a count of how many to display, that would be an integer value.  Or if you want a pre-defined set of elements that can show/hide individually, that would be an array.  Whatever data you need to use to dynamically build the UI and update over time, that data goes in state values.

Answer (score 0):

You would use a state variable for that.

```
import React, {useState} from 'react'
import Item from './Item';

import { icon, library } from '@fortawesome/fontawesome-svg-core';
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from '@fortawesome/react-fontawesome';
import { faPlusCircle} from '@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons';

library.add(faPlusCircle)

function row(props) {
      const [showItem, set_showItem] = useState


    return (
      <> // use react fragment here, otherwise you will get an error if you try to return several React Elements
        <ul className="global">

        {showItem? <Item> : null} // return the Item if you want to show it, otherwise return null
        
        <FontAwesomeIcon 
            onClick={()=> set_showItem(true)}
            con={["fas", "plus-circle"]}
        />
        <ul/>
      </> //ent of React fragment
    
        )
     }
```